# Particular case of Green’s theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, greens-theorem

Suppose we have $u(r)=\sum_{\lambda=1}^{\infty} a_{\lambda} u_{\lambda}(r) \quad 0 \leq r \leq a$ in this article [Introduction to R-matrix theory in atomic
physics](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/mariko.dunseath-terao/IP2004/psrmat1.pdf)

they say that
$$\int_{0}^{a}\left[u_{\lambda} \frac{d^{2} u}{d r^{2}}-u \frac{d^{2} u_{\lambda}}{d r^{2}}\right] dr=\left[u_{\lambda}\frac{du}{d r}-u \frac{du_{\lambda}}{d r}\right]_{r=a}$$

using Green’s theorem.
What is this  Green’s theorem they are talking?

Comment: Where does that right-hand side come from? The only reference to Green's theorem in the article is in equation $(1.6)$,$$a_\lambda=\frac1a\frac{u_\lambda(a)}{k_\lambda^2-k^2}\left[a\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dr}-bu\right]_{r=a}$$

Comment: that right-hand side comes from integration by parts. This is what he is calling Green's theorem

Answer (score 1):

One can only speculate, but perhaps they mean the 1D case of [Green's first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green%27s_first_identity) $\int_U (f \Delta g+ \nabla  f \cdot \nabla g) d V=\int_{\partial U} f \nabla g \cdot n dS$. In 1D this is (in the "indefinite" form) $\int  (f g''+f'g') dx=fg'$, so that

$$\int fg''-gf''dx=\left(\int fg''+f'g' dx\right)-\left(\int gf'' +f'g'dx\right)=fg'-gf'$$

This is of course an overkill in 1D, but maybe they were specializing from a higher dimensional case.